# Java Regex - Checking for Carriage Return

Tags: java, regex, whitespace, carriage-return

I am writing a regex to capture SQL Injection Keywords on the HTTP request.
I am having problems with allowing 0 or more carriage returns.

I have tried \s but I get the error 'errorInvalidEscaperChar'.

If I put \s then this will be taken as a literal \s.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

N

Comment: what sql flavour (database server) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to escape the `\` in your string. try `"\\s"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the backslash in Java Strings. So, to get a backslash followed by an s, you need to write: "`\\s`".

But let's take a step back, what are you trying to achieve? Searching in parameters for "SQL Injection Keywords" might be a bad idea. Could you provide some details?

Comment: Hi Tim,Thank you for your swift reply! I'm checking the HTTP request for SQL Keywords like 'insert into', 'delete' 'select' etc. My regex works fine if the user enters it as a String with no carriage returns in the form. When I enter a carriage return between SQL Keywords it doesn't pick it up. - - Hope that makes sense Tim! :)

Comment: And thus will quite happily continue with the action with SQL Keywords...possible SQL Injection.

Comment: You just have to make sure, the user isn't able to end the string. Keywords do harm only, if they outside of strings. There are methodes to escape SQL, like [Apache's EscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29), but when you're using PreparedStatements, you don't have that issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

"\" is a citation character in regexp and Java. So you need to write \\s